# Migrating struts 1.x app to struts 2.5.26

Tags: java, struts2, tiles, apache-tiles

We are migrating one of our old apps to Struts 2.5.26 due to security issue found in struts 1.x. While testing I noticed that tiles is throwing an exception when the server is coming up.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainerFactory(Lorg/apache/tiles/TilesApplicationContext;)Lorg/apache/tiles/factory/AbstractTilesContainerFactory;
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 21, 2021 8:21:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

We have the following in web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

and we have the following jars in WEB-INF/lib folder

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  21175 Apr 20 15:21 tiles-el-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089 161001 Apr 20 15:22 tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  50740 Apr 20 15:22 tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  59739 Apr 20 15:22 tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  24466 Apr 20 15:22 tiles-template-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  35898 Apr 20 15:22 tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  71270 Apr 20 15:36 tiles-request-api-1.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ryk6mkj 1049089  32629 Apr 20 15:54 tiles-portlet-2.2.2.jar
```

I see that createContainerFactory()method is abstract in AbstractTilesInitializer.java class. Not sure why it is not using implementations like StrutsTilesInitializer.java or other implementations?

Any clues why this is happening?

Comment: How are you doing your dependency management? Those are not the correct Tiles deps for S2.5.6. Unrelated, but a move from S1 to S2 for a security issue in S1 is... questionable; depending on which issue(s) it'd almost certainly be more cost-effective to deal w/ the security issue in situ, or move off Struts altogether since it's basically a rewrite anyway (unless you just really like S2--I do, but if I was rewriting something I would take other factors into account).

Comment: We were told my mgmt team that the audit resulted in finding out the security issue and asked us to migrate. I see we should use tiles 3. I can't find the struts-tiles.tld file.

Comment: Now I keep it as <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
 in jsp files. Not getting the above exception anymore but when I access the page which uses tiles, getting the exception in in image below

Comment: Personally, I would push back, since this is essentially a complete rewrite of all client-facing code (and potentially business logic if it was inappropriately tied to the web layer). I'm not against rewrites, but a *hasty* rewrite to meet auditing timelines is likely to cause more problems than it solves :)

Comment: New/separate questions should be asked as a separate question, and all details should be in the question, not in comments :)

Comment: Here is the new issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67200150/struts-2-tiles-3-access-issue