# Struts 2- Tiles 3 access issue

Tags: struts2, tiles, apache-tiles

When I access the app that I just migrated to struts 2 tiles 3, seeing the below error when the app tries to access the history action.
[image: Struts 2 - Tiles 3 access issue]

Comment: There's nothing here anyone could use to help--looks like there's either no route or there's a bad/missing tile definition.

Comment: Is there a complete example for struts 2 - tiles 3 example project? I tried to look around but nothing complete

Comment: https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/tiles maybe? I haven't run any of the example apps for some time.